# How to access exchange headers in the xquery?

Tags: apache-camel, xquery

Can not get values out of exchange headers in a xquery. Getting for example
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unresolved reference to variable $in.headers.sourceSystem.
It is described here https://camel.apache.org/xquery.html

I'm using camel 2.21.3 running in Spring boot.

```xml
<route id="exampleRoute">
            <from uri="direct:start" />
            <setHeader headerName="sourceSystem">
                <constant>PR0</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <transform>
                <xquery>
                   element item {$in.headers.sourceSystem}
                </xquery>
            </transform>
            <to uri="mock:result"/>
        </route>
```

Expected result would look like

```xml
<item>PR0</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very straightforward but could be mentioned in the documentation.

```xml
            <transform>
                <xquery>
                    declare variable $in.headers.sourceSystem external;
                    element item {$in.headers.sourceSystem}
                </xquery>
            </transform>
```

Comment: Mind doing a PR? [New documentation source](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-saxon/src/main/docs/xquery-component.adoc)

Comment: I see that it has been merged already. Thanks for making the world a slightly better place 